# Check if object is in an iterable using "is" identity instead of "==" equality

Tags: python, list, identity, equality

```
if object in lst:
    #do something
```

As far as I can tell, when you execute this statement it is internally checking `==` between `object` and every element in `lst`, which will refer to the `__eq__` methods of these two objects. This can have the implication of two distinct objects being "equal", which is usually desired if all of their attributes are the same.

However, is there a way to Pythonically achieve a predicate such as `in` where the underlying equality check is `is` - i.e. we're actually checking if the two references are to the same object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `any` function:

```py
if any(x is object for x in lst):
    # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

3list membership in python is dictated by the __contains__ dunder method. You can choose to overwrite this for a custom implementation if you want to use the normal "`in`" syntax:

```
class my_list(list):
    def __contains__(self, x):
        for y in self:
            if x is y:
                return True

        return False


4 in my_list([4, [3,2,1]])

>> True

[3,2,1] in my_list([4, [3,2,1]])  # Because while the lists are "==" equal, they have different pointers.

>>> False
```

Otherwise, I'd suggest kaya3's answer of using a generator check.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to specifically use `is` then just use filter like:

```py
filtered_list = filter(lambda n: n is object, list)
```